# Gitlab Job variable to use in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to create a pipeline and have defined some variable in my gitlab job which will be used by python script to populate results.

Is there any way I can call/define those variable in my python script.

For example:

```
.test-report:
  extends: .test_report_setup
  tags: *def_runners_tags
  variables:
    value-path: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/value
```

Now in my python script I want to call the variable 'value-path' to fetch or read files located in that directory. (Please note that variable is a custom variable on gitlab)

```
file_path = '<value-path>'    <---- To get the gitlab job variable here

file_in = open(file_path + "id.txt")
```

Please help me how I can get it in my python script as I am a bit stuck on it.

Any suggestion/help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access environment variables with [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) or [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv). `os.environ` is a dict with the environment variables and will fail if you attempt to retrieve a key that doesn't exist. `os.getenv` is basically `os.environ.get`, which allows you to set a default value if there is no environment variable with that name.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with custom variables, I have custom variable defined and not the environment variable. How can I pull the custom variable in my python script.

Comment: the values defined in `variables` in the `gitlab-ci.yml` are stored as environment variables.  You can check this (and verify their values are as expected) by adding `env | sort` as a step in `script`. Check out the docs for more info: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#create-a-custom-cicd-variable-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file